# Configuartion for Pear DB Library

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to connect to MYSQL database using the Pear DB library. IS there any settings i need to do if i want to work with Pear DB library?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any specific kind of error ? If so, can you post a short version of your code (which reproduces the problem), and the error message you're obtaining ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need additional settings to use DB with MySQL.  Note that DB has been superceded by [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2), though.  Since you're doing MySQL, you should use that.  Note that you'll need either the [MDB2_Driver_mysql](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysql) or [MDB2_Driver_mysqli](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysqli)